# java-ERROR 70572 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Start error.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-01 17:44:55.214 ERROR 70717 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryTables' defined in com.example.restaurant.repository.RepositoryTables defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.example.restaurant.repository.RepositoryTables
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:934) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.example.restaurant.Main.main(Main.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.example.restaurant.repository.RepositoryTables
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:232) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:181) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
... 21 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml file.

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.3
 

com.example
restaurant
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
restaurant
restaurant

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-freemarker


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


org.springframework.session
spring-session-core

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please add a description of your problem at the top of the question

Comment: can you add code of `com.example.restaurant.repository.RepositoryTables`?

Comment: @Egor 'package com.example.restaurant.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RepositoryTables extends JpaRepository<RepositoryTables,Integer> {
}
'

Comment: @Egor, thank you, i found the problem where you mentioned